# how to hide articles page from home page in drupal

Tags: views, nodes

I have added article page in my project and made Views for that, but articles page also display on the front page. How to hide article from home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to untick "Promoted to front page " on structure / content types / your content types / publishing options, for every content type you have.

Comment: Or you can change your homepage to a node in Configuration -> System -> Site Information

Comment: I had Crate view of that all news ,I want to add Author details in view as one field how can I ?